# How to apply rollapply/rollmean to multiple dataframes?

Tags: r

I've been trying to create new column with roll mean for each of my dataframes.

I'm trying to use lapply with rollmean/rollaply from ZOO package. It is natural that after counting rollmean some of tail and head observations will be empty.

```
library(zoo)

df.list <- list(alpha, beta, gamma)
lapply(df.list, function(w) { w$rolling <- rollapply(w$tmean, width = 3, FUN = mean, fill=NA); w})
```

When I call `lapply` with `rollapply` nested individually using `fill=NA` it works fine. When I put it into a loop/`lapply` with multiple DFs i get

```
"Error in attr(x, "class") <- attr(x, "oclass") : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object ".
```

If i drop `fill=NA` option I get

```
"replacement has 6208 rows, data has 6210".
```

Any clue how to overcome this?

Comment: r2evans thank you for the edit, I was already doing it but it seems you were faster :)

Comment: You need `fill=NA`, period. As to your `"factor"` error, we cannot know without seeing something of your data (and it is unrelated to the fact that it is a list-of-frames). It would help to be able to see an unambiguous sample of *one* of the frames that cause that error, such as with `dput(head(alpha))`.

Comment: Unfortunately my datasets contain more than 300 variables each, but I can assure that all of them are just numeric variables. Can I help in the other way?

Comment: Okay, `dput(alpha[1:5,1:5])`. The point is to provide us something to play with. Frankly, we only need 1-2 columns of data to be rolled, perhaps a column that doesn't (to prove the concept works in the presence of other data), and sufficient rows to roll somewhat-meaningfully without breaking the browser window with gobs of data. It can be `mtcars` or something else, so you only need to show the public dataset's name.

Comment: Okay, it occured that one of my columns contains "," instead of "." as a decimal. Gsub function did the job!